# JQuery :nth-child() append

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have simple list:

```
<ul>
<li>some text 1 </li>
<li>some text 2</li>
<li>some text 3</li>
<li>some text 4</li>
<li>some text 5</li>
<li>some text 6</li>
<li>some text 7</li>
</ul>
```

I need add after each 4n element some div

I have:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(4n)").after("<div style='color:black'>test</div>");
```

But for example I have 4 elements and my div after it, and than I have only 3 element, but I need append my div after third element...How to make this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add) to add to the jQuery resultset the last `li` ,if it is not matched by the `nth-child` rule..

```
$("ul li:nth-child(4n)")
    .add('ul li:last')
    .after("<div style='color:black'>test</div>");
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/a8vAU/

Answer (score 2):

you can also rely on grep to do the picking:

```
var $lis = $('li');

$lis = $($.grep($lis, function (l, i) {return (i+1)%4 == 0 || i == $lis.length - 1;}));

$lis.after("<div style='color:black'>test</div>");
```

Comment: but this ain't as sleek as Gabys solution.